# Sync device data with web-server

Tags: java, performance, queue, android-sqlite, android-networking

I have data in my application which must be updated on the server on the basis of network availability. I store this data on a local database on android using sqlite. Currently the idea is:

1. Data should be inserted on the local sqlite database
2. A service should be waiting as soon as the data is inserted it checks the network availability and send it to the server and wait for success response.
3. If the response true is received from the server it should update the sync status of that sqlite row and move to the next row to send the data.

I wanted to find out the best way to queue this data to send it to the server, additionally this queue should stop sending data to the server when the network is unavailable. Since there are lot of queues available in java which queu is the best to hold this data. Since the data can grow to any infinite size. It is a like a Producer-Consumer problem but what is the most efficient way to address it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you found the solution. I have to do same thing. please post your code as answer with a little description. thank you

Comment: Use Linked Blocking Queue as they are available in Java. When you insert a data into database, update the queue at the same time.

Comment: can you please provide some links or tutorials on it. thank you

Comment: Use this link to understand the Linked Blocking Queue:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html

Once you develop a prototype share it, and I will help you to improve based on what you have developed.

Comment: Are you able to come up with solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you store this data in a queue when it is already stored in a local database? I mean what happens if your application is shut down then the data in the queue is lost. Just write a service that checks the local database for new entries. If there are new entries try to push them to the webserver.

Comment: Yes, you are right. A data in the queue will be lost and it is unnecessary to hold data in the queue. But what is the best way to check the data from the local db. I mean that making a thread and have a loop for continuous checking data will unnecessarily use the cpu cycles. What should be the most effective way to deal this.

Comment: We can use broadcast receiver in this case, but what if this broadcast receiver is fired more than once (like user continuously tapping a button which add rows in the database). In this case, broadcast will be fired as many times as the user taps the button.
Where the execution of the previous request is already taking place, and concurrent fires will send the same data multiple time.