# Scheduled alarms are not firing properly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

My application schedules multiple alarms for particular times. These alarms are scheduled when the application starts. (For each day there are 5 alarms resulting in 35 alarms per week)...

I have verified through logs that these alarms are scheduled when the application starts.

The problem is when I started testing my application the 7 alarms goes off perfectly fine. However the 8th alarm doesn't fired. I have tested this scenario by keeping my device still for more than 1 day. How can I debug this behaviour and what are the possible reasons that prevent alarm for firing.

*Edit:*

Code for scheduling:

```
try {
    if (info != null) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, info.getHour());
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, info.getMinute());
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiverActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", info.getPrayerName());
        intent.putExtra("sound", soundType);

        intent.putExtra("time", formatTimeClock(context, info.getHour(), info.getMinute()));

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, alarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("ALarmSchedularManager", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: can you able to show your AlarmManager setRepeating code portion

Comment: Shared code for scheduling alarm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I debug this behaviour

Use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see what your scheduled alarms are and when they are next to be invoked.

> what are the possible reasons that prevent alarm for firing

Your code does not appear take into account the possibility that the time has already passed, though that may be handled outside the code snippet you show above.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me how to comprehend the system dumpsys:
RTC_WAKEUP #723: Alarm{41d63e98 type 0 com.example}
    type=0 when=+3d11h33m50s418ms repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{41882d80: PendingIntentRecord{41d63df8 com.athan startActivity}}

Correct me if I am wrong:
#723: Alarm Id
when: time in milliseconds from base.
repeatInterval: This is not a repeating alarm

Comment: @Maverick: The "when" indicates that your alarm will next go off three days, eleven hours, thirty-three minutes, fifty seconds, and four hundred and eighteen milliseconds from the time you ran the `dumpsys` command.

Comment: btw, it'll great if you can also have a look at:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/14952076/1053097

I am having a hard time developing a failsafe queue for sending network requests.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully below code will help, I used the same in my app. Here the argument passed in AlarmManager class for repeating should be 24*60*60*1000

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);         
Intent intent1 = new Intent(ct, TimeAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Date curr=new Date();
curr.setHours(h);
curr.setMinutes(m);
c.setTime(curr);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(),24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

instead of hard code manipulation (24*60*60*1000) you can use AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY. Check this for different interval upto 1 day http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#INTERVAL_DAY

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use setRepeating here because the user can always update the individual alarms.

Comment: You can. Just store the Intent you used to set the Alarm, and use `am.cancel(mPendingIntent)` if the user changes the alarm. Then set the new one.

Comment: This should be the way you do it by the way, use setRepeating with inexact Intervals. else your app will drain A LOT of battery.